# Converting letter to Morse code only works for one letter each run

Tags: java, morse-code

I am trying to output the Morse code alphabet. Currently I map an inputted letter to its corresponding Morse code letter. The problem I am having is that after I input one letter, following letters will give no output.

My code is below:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = createAlphabet();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();

        for (Map.Entry<String , String> entry : map.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        }

    }

    public static Map<String , String> createAlphabet() {
        Map<String , String> alphabet = new HashMap<>();

        alphabet.put("A" , ".-");
        alphabet.put("B" , "-...");
        alphabet.put("C" , "-.-");
        alphabet.put("D" , "-..");
        alphabet.put("E" , ".");
        alphabet.put("F" , "..-.");
        alphabet.put("G" , "--.");
        alphabet.put("H" , "....");
        alphabet.put("I" , "..");
        alphabet.put("J" , ".---");
        alphabet.put("K" , "-.-");
        alphabet.put("L" , ".-..");
        alphabet.put("M" , "--");
        alphabet.put("N" , "-.");
        alphabet.put("O" , "---");
        alphabet.put("P" , ".--");
        alphabet.put("Q" , "--.-");
        alphabet.put("R" , ".-.");
        alphabet.put("S" , "...");
        alphabet.put("T" , "-");
        alphabet.put("U" , "..-");
        alphabet.put("V" , "...-");
        alphabet.put("W" , ".--");
        alphabet.put("X" , "-..-");
        alphabet.put("Y" , "-.--");
        alphabet.put("Z" , "--..");


        return alphabet;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Your program has compilation errors.   It won't work if you can't compile it.   2) The point of a map is that you *look up* a key using the `get(...)` method.  3) The string "BD" is not a key for the table.  The keys are all one-character strings.  So, you need to lookup one character strings.  Now we could fix your code for you, but that **defeats the purpose** of your homework / exercise.  So I recommend that you take these hints and figure out how to fix the program for yourself.

Comment: @StephenC to be fair, it's quite common on SO to omit import statements in the interest of brevity when showing code. With the usual imports it compiles ok.

Comment: If the OP posts code he / she wants help with debugging, and the code does not compile, then it is not an MCVE, and the question is off-topic.  To be fair ... I have actually provided the OP with a significant amount of help!

Comment: It may be better to use `Map<Character, String>` instead of `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: @JeRiF did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It will only read one value, since this code is executed once, and you are not getting the letter if you are passing a word, for example.

You type 'D' it will print "-..", because it's one character, but if you type 'HELLO' it won't print the full word because you need to separe by chars and print it one by one.

If you change your loop to this, it will do what you want :

```
for (Map.Entry<String , String> entry : map.entrySet()){
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)))){
                System.out.print(entry.getValue() + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

By the way if you want to avoid to run the app every time you can create a flag to keep typing and converting until you want something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = createAlphabet();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    while(!s.equals(".")){
        for (Map.Entry<String , String> entry : map.entrySet()){
            for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
                if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)))){
                    System.out.print(entry.getValue() + " ");
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

### Edit

As suggested by @Stephen C I changed the code to this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = createAlphabet();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        while (!s.equals(".")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                System.out.print(map.get((String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))))+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            s = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

It's pointless using a for when you have the [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method

Comment: Except .... why would you iterate the entries of a map?  Use `get`.   And I don't think this code does what the OP is actually *trying* to do: convert words into morse code.

Comment: Updated the answer @StephenC, I was just following his code, you're right this is better.

Comment: And I don't think this code does what the OP is actually trying to do: convert words into morse code > This code if you put Hello it will print Hello in morse, did you try it?

Comment: I commented on your initial rewrite of the loop ... which if I read it correctly will randomize the letters in the word while translating.   (Which is what the OP's code would do if he was looking up single character strings, but which is not correct.)   Your later EDIT doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Why would it randomize? It's a for loop that starts from h and ends in o if the word is hello, right? And now, the answer is ok?

Comment: Because you are translating and printing the letters in the order of the keys in the map (random) not the order of the letters in the input string.   (If the map was a `TreeMap`, your code would work ....)   Now you may get lucky ... and the keys in the map may be in a serendipitous order when iterated.  But you shouldn't count on it,.

Comment: Oh, I got you now, yes, it will print first "E", then "H", and so.. ok, yes good point ;)